# Can you calculate the rate of a present value annuity due with np.rate without a future value?

Tags: python, numpy

Using [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=7253.93%20%3D%201000*(1-(1%2Br)%5E(-9))%2Fr,%20solve%20for%20r) the future value is not required to iteratively find the rate in a [present value annuity due calculation](http://financeformulas.net/Present_Value_of_Annuity_Due.html).

When I try using [np.rate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rate.html) it requires the future value:

```
In [3]: np.rate(10, 1000, 8253.93)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-224d3b6f0859> in <module>()
----> 1 np.rate(10, 1000, 8253.93)

TypeError: rate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fv'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not understanding the cash flow. I needed to ensure the `PMT` was a negative cash flow. Therefore:

```
In [21]: np.rate(10, -1000, 8253.93, 0, when=1)
Out[21]: 0.04545455285667707
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.  The relationship for an investment with periodic payments has five variables.  To compute any one variable, you need the other four values.

However, the root cause of your problem is that you've used the wrong function.  The Wolfram item you cite *does* include both the starting (1000) and future values, 7253.03, but has no periodic payment.  In contrast, `np.rate` returns the periodic rate, given the other figures *and* a payment per period.

You can solve what I think is your intended problem by supplying either a periodic payment of 0.00 or a starting value of 0.00, depending on the application.  Your final value of 7253.93 is significantly *less* than 10*1000.00, so I suspect you want 10000.00 as the starting value.

[rate doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rate.html)
[Use examples](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/102103/numpy.rate)

Comment: No, it does not include the present value. According to the [formula](http://financeformulas.net/Present_Value_of_Annuity_Due.html) the 1000 is the periodic payment. There is no future value used.

Comment: Ah -- thanks for the larger-print version :-)  Yes, I mis-read the original.  Still, the base problem is that you called a function that includes one more parameter, a 0.00 you didn't supply.  Put that in place, and you shoudl get the solution you need.